# How to get a Date from date_select or select_date in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, parameters

Using `select_date` gives me back a `params[:my_date]` with `year`, `month` and `day` attributes. How do get a Date object easily? I'm hoping for something like `params[:my_date].to_date`.

I'm happy to use `date_select` instead as well.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using date_select gives you 3 separate key/value pairs for the day, month, and year respectively. So you can pass them into `Date.new` as parameters to create a new Date object.

An example date_select returned params for an `Event` model:

```
"event"=>
 {"name"=>"Birthday",
  "date(1i)"=>"2012",
  "date(2i)"=>"11",
  "date(3i)"=>"28"},
```

Then to create the new `Date` object:

```
event = params[:event]
date = Date.new event["date(1i)"].to_i, event["date(2i)"].to_i, event["date(3i)"].to_i
```

You may instead decide to wrap this logic in a method:

```
def flatten_date_array hash
  %w(1 2 3).map { |e| hash["date(#{e}i)"].to_i }
end
```

And then call it as `date = Date.new *flatten_date_array params[:event]`.  But this is not logic that truly belongs in a controller, so you may decide to move it elsewhere. You could even extend this onto the `Date` class, and call it as `date = Date.new_from_hash params[:event]`.

Comment: Very surprising that Rails doesn't include a simple conversion mechanism as they already have a hidden mechanism when attaching date selects to a model. I found in the Rails Guides documentation they suggest to use `Date.civil`, what's the difference between that and `Date.new`?

Comment: @at. According to ruby docs, `Date.civil` and `Date.new` are completely identical.  I've always used `Date.new` as its more OOP-ish. And yea I agree with you, I was also surprised it isn't built into rails.  But a simple 1 line method like the one above is a pretty easy fix.

Comment: doesn't sound too difficult to implement as part of rails

Answer (score 14):

Here is another one:

```
# view
<%= date_select('event', 'date') %>

# controller
date = Date.civil(*params[:event].sort.map(&:last).map(&:to_i))
```

Found at http://kevinlochner.com/use-rails-dateselect-without-an-activerecord

Comment: It works for me. I would avoid double mapping like     date = Date.civil(*params[:event].sort.map{ |d| d.last.to_i })

Answer (score 5):

I use the following method, which has the following benefits:

1. it doesn't have to explicitly name param keys `xxx(1i)` through `xxx(3i)` (and thus could be modified to capture hour and minute simply by changing `Date` to `DateTime`); and
2. it extracts a date from a set of `params` even when those params are populated with many other key-value pairs.

`params` is a hash of the format `{ xxx(1i): '2017', xxx(2i): 12, xxx(3i): 31, ... }`; `date_key` is the common substring `xxx` of the target date parameters.

```
def date_from_params(params, date_key)
  date_keys = params.keys.select { |k| k.to_s.match?(date_key.to_s) }.sort
  date_array = params.values_at(*date_keys).map(&:to_i)
  Date.civil(*date_array)
end
```

I chose to place this as a class method of `ApplicationRecord`, rather than as an instance helper method of `ApplicationController`. My reasoning is that similar logic exists within the ActiveRecord instantiator (*i.e.,* `Model.new`) to parse dates passed in from Rails forms.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the another one

```
Date.civil(params[:event]["date(1i)"].to_i,params[:event]["date(2i)"].to_i,params[:event]["date(3i)"].to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one for rails 5:

```
module Convert
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included  do
    before_action :convert_date
  end

  protected

  def convert_date
    self.params = ActionController::Parameters.new(build_date(params.to_unsafe_h))
  end

  def build_date(params)
    return params.map{|e| build_date(e)} if  params.is_a? Array

    return params unless params.is_a? Hash

    params.reduce({}) do |hash, (key, value)|
      if result = (/(.*)\(\di\)\z/).match(key)
        params_name = result[1]
        date_params = (1..3).map do |index|
          params.delete("#{params_name}(#{index}i)").to_i
        end
        hash[params_name] =  Date.civil(*date_params)
      else
        hash[key] = build_date(value)
      end

      hash
    end
  end
end
```

You need to include it to your controller or application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Convert
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With the date_select example @joofsh's answer, here's a "one liner" I use, presuming the date field is called `start_date`:

```
ev_params = params[:event]

date = Time.zone.local(*ev_params.select {|k,v| k.to_s.index('start_date(') == 0 }.sort.map {|p| p[1].to_i})
```