# What is the best way to handle date in a Rails Form Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I'm using Form Object as described in [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models #3](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) and currently I have an issue with storing date.

Here's what I've done:

```
class MyModelForm
  # ...

  def initialize(my_model: MyModel.new, params: {})
    @my_model, @params = my_model, params
    @my_model.date_field_on = Date.from_params @params, "date_field_on" if @params.present?
  end
end
```

Where `Date.from_params` is implemented like:

```
class Date
  def self.from_params(params, field_name)
    begin
      year = params["#{ field_name }(1i)"]
      month = params["#{ field_name }(2i)"]
      day = params["#{ field_name }(3i)"]

      Date.civil year.to_i, month.to_i, day.to_i if year && month && day
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      # catch that because I don't want getting error when date cannot be parsed (invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot just use `@my_model.assign_attributes @params.slice(*ACCEPTED_ATTRIBUTES)` because my `params["date_field_on(<n>i)"]` will be skipped and date will not be stored.

Is there a better approach to handle date fields using Form Objects?

Comment: that's really a good question. i did not see a helper for extracting these date values. i find that kind of odd!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605598/how-to-get-a-date-from-date-select-or-select-date-in-rails

Comment: My first strategy would be to delegate that to the model, since AR handles that pretty well. My second strategy would be to use Virtus, as in the "7 Patterns" example.

Comment: Yes. It's works great with Virtus. Thank you. If you will add answer based on your comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @davidfurber mentioned in comments it works great with [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem.

```
class MyModelForm
  include Virtus

  # ...
  attribute :date_field_on, Date

  def initialize(params: {})
    @my_model.assign_attributes params
  end
end
```