# How to get the value of date_select field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the value of the `date_select` field in my controller. I also need to add an if statement so that if the value is nil it won't try to get the data and trow an error.

Here's my date_select field :

```
<%= date_select :regdate, :date, order: [:year, :month] %>
```

Here's the params in the debug :

```
regdate: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  date(3i): '1'
  date(1i): '2014'
  date(2i): '10'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Date from date\_select or select\_date in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605598/how-to-get-a-date-from-date-select-or-select-date-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller side

```
regdate =  Date.new(params["regdate(1i)"].to_i,
                    params["regdate(2i)"].to_i,
                    params["regdate(3i)"].to_i)
```

or this, whatever coming in your params

```
regdate =  Date.new(params["date(1i)"].to_i,
                    params["date(2i)"].to_i,
                    params["date(3i)"].to_i)
```

Comment: In both the cases i get an error saying "Invalid date", My params hash is posted above. I have regdate and under that date(...)

Comment: I used this `@date = Date.new(params[:regdate]["date(1i)"].to_i,
                    params[:regdate]["date(2i)"].to_i,
                    params[:regdate]["date(3i)"].to_i)` Now no errors but no result. I tried to output it on the view as @date.to_s, no result

Answer (score 0):

I think this notation looks nicer in code:

`foo = Date.new(*params[:foo].map { |_, v| v.to_i })`

That requires you to set the `prefix` option in `date_select`, which moves all inputs for year, month and day into an hash:

`<%= f.date_select 'start_date', prefix: 'foo'} %>`

Answer (score 0):

In the controller use

```
@regdate = params
```

And inner the view

```
<%= @regdate["regdate"]["date(3i)"]  %>
<%= @regdate["regdate"]["date(2i)"]  %>
<%= @regdate["regdate"]["date(1i)"]  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found date_select to be a bit tricky because of the format of the params it will generate, but to use the question at hand, here's a full explaination. Starting with the view:

```
# View
= date_select :regdate, :date, order: [:year, :month]
```

Above code will give a Year and a Month selector. So in the params that will be passed to the backend/rails app:

```
# Console
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "regdate"=>{"date(3i)"=>"1", "date(1i)"=>"2014", "date(2i)"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
```

You are only looking for the first two values: Year, month

In backend/controller use following code to convert the params back into a date of any kind:

```
# Controller
selected_date =  Date.new(
  params[:download_date]["download_date(1i)"].to_i,
  params[:download_date]["download_date(2i)"].to_i
  ).strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Note that attaching .strftime("%Y%m%d") at the end of the Date object will let to format the resulting date in any way you like. In this case it will result in:

```
201403
```