# Rails date_select values always 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying for a while but I can't seem to access date_select values.

The view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |form| %>

  ...

  <%= form.label :release_date %>
  <%= date_select :@product, :release_date %>

  ...
```

When the form is submitted I can see that the values are definitely there as the POST contains:

```
Parameters: ... "product"=> { "@product"=>{"release_date(1i)"=>"2016", "release_date(2i)"=>"4", "release_date(3i)"=>"13"} ... }
```

From the answer to a similar question; [How to get a Date from date_select or select_date in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605598/how-to-get-a-date-from-date-select-or-select-date-in-rails)  it would seem that the correct code to get the value from the key "release_date(1i)" should be something like:

```
product = params[:product] 
date = product["release_date(1i)"].to_i
```

However the value for date is always 0.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: if you `puts params[:product]` in your controller, what does it look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
<%= date_select :@product, :release_date %>
```

to

```
<%= form.date_select :release_date %>
```

so you will get the ideal params

```
Parameters: ... "product"=> {"release_date(1i)"=>"2016", "release_date(2i)"=>"4", "release_date(3i)"=>"13"} ... }
```

and so you can do

```
product = params[:product] 
date = product["release_date(1i)"].to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `do |form|` in your form_for tag, you need to bind the `release_date` to the form's model like so:

```
<%= form.date_select :release_date %>
```