# Processing multiple controller parameters into a single model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, strong-parameters

#### EDIT

It turns out I misunderstood how the `#date_select` form helper method works — I arrived at the approach below based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606990/4865822), but after some tinkering, [I discovered that, in typical Rails fashion, `#date_select` actually handles the whole thing automagically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754039/4865822).

In any case, there are still times when I'd like to do something similar: for instance, if I want to capture a single `User.tenure` attribute as a serialized hash (`{ start: <year>, end: <year> }`), and I implement this in the view form as two separate fields that return the parameters `:tenure_start` and `:tenure_end`.

Where would the logic go to convert these two parameters into a single model attribute?

---

#### My problem, specifically

I want to have a "date-of-birth" attribute for the `User` model in my application. The New User form uses Rails' built-in [`#date_select` form helper method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select).

In the view, `#date_select` creates three separate drop-down menus for year, month, and day. In the controller, it [returns three separate parameters](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select#422-Date-select-with-assert-valid-keys): `dob(1i)`, `dob(2i)`, and `dob(3i)`. Each of these parameters is a string representation of its respective field (*e.g.,* if you select 1992/7/14, the parameter values are `"1992"`, `"07"`, and `"14"`).

I want to convert these three string parameters into a single `Date` object and assign it to a new `User`.

---

#### The question, generally

My understanding of MVC is that the controller should be thin: its job is merely to pass information between the model and the view. But in the above case, there are controller parameters that don't have corresponding model attributes. Thus,

```
User.create(user_params)
```

doesn't work, because `User::new` doesn't accept the `:"dob(1i)"` attribute (and wouldn't know what to do with it if it did). They need to be processed into a single value with something like

```
dob = params.fetch(:player).values_at(%i(dob(1i) dob(2i) dob(3i))).map(&:to_i)
params.fetch(:player)[:dob] = { player: { dob: Date.new(dob[0], dob[1], dob[2]) } }
```

before they can be saved into the `dob` attribute.

My question is this: **How much of this logic belongs in the controller, and how much belongs in the model?**

- Should the controller be left to handle conversion of the input, and instantiate the model with exactly the data it needs?
- or should the controller simply concatenate the three fields into a single string (*e.g.,* `"19920714"`) and leave it to the model to convert it to a `Date` before saving?
- or is there a way to pass the three raw, unprocessed parameters into a model object and have *it* handle the conversion?
- or is there another possibility I haven't thought of?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605598/how-to-get-a-date-from-date-select-or-select-date-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to store actual date in database

```
 year = "1992"
 month = "14"
 day = "07"
 dob = m + '/' + d + '/' + y
=> Date.parse(dob)
=> Tue, 14 Jul 1992
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm more curious to know _where_ to place this logic, not _how_ to get it done.

Comment: @RyanLue  In your controller, you can add this before insert the record, or you can also write method, and add this logic, call that method before action of insert data. you can accept my answer. if it is helpful to you :)

Comment: I appreciate the insight, but to clarify even further, I'm looking for an answer to how it _should_ be done (according to MVC principles), not how it _can_ be done.

Comment: @RyanLue Okay let me create a example.